# Spyder (Anaconda) Not Running because of some errors

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

When I am trying to run the spyder (Anaconda) I am getting the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 205, in main
mainwindow.main()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3651, in main
mainwindow = run_spyder(app, options, args)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 3526, in run_spyder
main.setup()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 945, in setup
from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.plugin import IPythonConsole
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 46, in 
from spyder.plugins.ipythonconsole.widgets import (ClientWidget,
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\__init__.py", line 16, in 
from .debugging import DebuggingWidget
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\widgets\debugging.py", line 13, in 
import pdb
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pdb.py", line 138, in 
class Pdb(bdb.Bdb, cmd.Cmd):
AttributeError: module 'cmd' has no attribute 'Cmd'
```

Can someone please health me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a file with the name **cmd.py**. After deleting the file (or rename the file), my problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have a file named cmd.py in the same directory as the file you are trying to execute?
Cause If you are, then `import cmd` would not import the right python module. Instead, it would import your created "cmd.py" file.

I too faced this issue cause I had a file named "cmd.py" along with my python scripts and it would import that whenever I said `import cmd`. Renaming it helped me solve the issue